# Putting a space between the buttons

Tags: shortcode, buttons

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[su_button url="http://google.com/checkout/" target="self" background="#2D89EF" color="#FFFFFF" size="3" wide="no" center="no" radius="auto" icon="icon: shopping-cart" icon_color="#FFFFFF" text_shadow="none" desc="" onclick="" class=""]Buy now            $149[/su_button]'); ?>
```

so right now the button says Buy Now $149 but I want to put 2 more spaces between the text. Manually inserting spaces doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is less of a WordPress question and more of a styling questions but here is some feedback anyway.

You could create a class and use your themes style.css or for examples below, inline CSS. You can either use the word-spacing property or left/right padding on some span elements to get the desired spacing.

```
<?php 

echo do_shortcode('[su_button url="http://google.com/checkout/" target="self" background="#2D89EF" color="#FFFFFF" size="3" wide="no" center="no" radius="auto" icon="icon: shopping-cart" icon_color="#FFFFFF" text_shadow="none" desc="" onclick="" class=""]<span style="word-spacing: 30px;">Buy now $149</span>[/su_button]'); 

?>
```

Or...

```
<?php 

echo do_shortcode('[su_button url="http://google.com/checkout/" target="self" background="#2D89EF" color="#FFFFFF" size="3" wide="no" center="no" radius="auto" icon="icon: shopping-cart" icon_color="#FFFFFF" text_shadow="none" desc="" onclick="" class=""]<span style="padding-right:40px;">Buy now </span>$149[/su_button]'); 

?>
```